# Access SSH Tunnel from Remote Location

Tags: ssh, openvpn, raspberry-pi, ssh-tunnel

I created an openVPN server on my raspberry pi, but am traveling to China soon. I have heard that my vpn will not be accessible and that I would want to access it. I have learnt that you can go past it with an ssh tunnel, but I cannot access it from a remote location. Can someone please help me create an ash tunnel and access it from a remote location? Thank you!

Comment: Please make sure that this doesn't violate the chinese law, otherwise you could get into **big** trouble...

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it doesn't and I need a way to do what I need.

Comment: I learned of this because someone told of using the ssh tunnel because he had done the same, but he didn't elaborate

Comment: And I do not plan to use this too much, but just for basics

Answer (score 0):

If you only need an ssh conexion you can port forward your router and use a no-ip dinamyc dns name to conect back withouth losing your public ip.
Disable password auth and generate a key to grant you access with key based authentication. Probably no one will hax you

First register here
https://www.noip.com/

Some routers have DynDNS freatures, check if your router supports it. 
If not you should install the no-ip client in a host inside your network

What it does is to connect into no-ip servers and is always notifying wich is your public IP

In case you reboot the router and you get a new public IP, the No-IP client will notify the servers and update the dns records

How to Configure on your router:
Search for the freature, the router will have a integrated client wich only ask you to login into your no-ip account

How to Configure on Linux
www noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client/

How to configure in Windows:
www noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-windows-4-x-dynamic-update-client-duc/

SSH key authentication linux to linux
www digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server

SSH key authentication using putty
www digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-digitalocean-droplets-windows-users

PUT A PASSWORD ON THE KEY
And dont lose the key file, if u lose it u will cannot login in to your raspberry

For the connection i recoment you to disable root login from ssh and create other user to login and then use su to get root access if you need.

Then to connect from outside you can use the dns name provided with noip

ssh user@no-ip.something.gg

Check that it is working before you leave outside

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63446/discussion-on-answer-by-angel-porlan-access-ssh-tunnel-from-remote-location).